# Magento remove shipping information and shipping method but keep shipping costs

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on Magento and the checkout process do have 5 steps, but I need to cut it down to three, I want to remove Shipping information, and Shipping method, but I still need the shipping costs.

My problem is when I move those two steps, there is always free shipping, but I need to keep the shipping costs, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

First remove shipping and shipping method steps,
good example: [Remove steps](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-shipping-method-step)

override OnepageCheckoutController
force use of billing address as shipping address and manualy set shipping method, for example 'flatrate'

Comment: Can you explain that? - Because on the link you sent it looks like I need an extension, it do not show any url to find the files to edit. It just says edit your module's config.xml.

Comment: oh, you have to build Your own extension and override magento checkout files, sorry but there's no "easy" way to disable checkout steps and still use shipping cost

Comment: Okay, but don't you think there is an extension there can do that, that I can buy somewhere?